# How to IOS mobile app displays notifications, reads them, and automatically sends a reply

Tags: swift, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have implemented a functionality that allows users to set up an auto-reply for notifications by reading text notifications. This functionality works seamlessly with Android devices. However, it doesn't work the same way with iOS devices. I achieved this using a Flutter plugin reference called "reflex 0.0.2."

I would like to inquire if there is a method to achieve the auto-reply functionality for iOS devices.